# Rails4: How to create Image Links with Hover?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, hover, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails 4.0.1 app that shows a set of image links on the homepage. Rails gets the image names from the Industry model. Each image should show a hover image on mouseover.

I've tried this:

```
<% @industries.each_with_index do |i,n| %>

    <li class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
         <%= link_to image_tag(i.img_full, alt: i.name, class: 'industry_thumb', mouseover: i.img_full_mo), companies_path(industry: i.name) %>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

However, this results in this HTML:

```
<li class="col-md-2">
    <a href="/companies?industry=Personalberatung">
         <img alt="Personalberatung" class="industry_thumb" mouseover="branchen_personalber_mo.png" src="/assets/branchen_personalber.png">
    </a>
</li>
```

When I was expecting the mouseover: to work like described here:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag

I found not too many articles about this issue which is why I'm guessing there's an alternative way using CSS. However, how would I achieve the same effect with CSS if I want to dynamically generate the image links? Unfortunately, moving the default and the hover image into one image and using something like this:

```
 .button-class {
   border: 0;
   background: url('../assets/images/button.png') no-repeat 0 0px;
 }
 .button-class:hover {
    background: url('../assets/images/button.png') no-repeat 0 20px;
 }
```

isn't possible in this case. Unless there's an automatic way to combine the two images during assets:precompile?

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
image_tag(class_door(student_class), onMouseover: "this.src='/assets/open_door.png';", onMouseout: "this.src='/assets/closed_door.png'" )
```

I have the above code is working for me , note that class_door(student_class) is a helper in my application

the mouse over method is `onMouseover:` not `mouseover:`

Comment: this works, thanks. However, shouldn't there be a way that's compliant with 
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag
?

Comment: well i don't know why there is no complaint about it maybe others uses   javascript outside the code to do a mouse over, but for me i tried to follow the same link and it was not work , then after search i found `onMouseover` so i tried it. if you consider my solution as an answer you can accept it

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
.col-md-2 a img:hover{
    /*Your hover values should be here*/
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this to be consistent with the asset pipeline way:

```
image_tag(class_door(student_class), onMouseover: "this.src='#{image_url("/assets/open_door.png")}';", onMouseout: "this.src='#{image_url("/assets/closed_door.png")}'" )
```